# Can I set RT priority to user level threads?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Can I set RT priority to user level threads? If no, what are the priority levels defined for user process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See `sched_setscheduler(2)`. Use either `SCHED_FIFO` or `SCHED_RR`. Unless you have two different threads with the exact same priority in `SCHED_RR`, they are basically identical.

(For the pthreads version, see the analogous `pthread_setschedparam(3)`.